# Slow Boot: Ethernet Wait

Tags: networking, boot, troubleshooting, minibian

I am using Minibian(lightweight version of Raspbian) and if the Pi is not connected to a network it will wait a whole minute before finishing booting.

I noticed that if I commented out lines 3 and 4 in `/etc/network/interfaces` the Pi would boot in a normal amount of time. However, I then lost the ability to SSH into my Pi. When I want fast boots this is what my `/etc/network/interfaces` file looks like:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

#auto eth0
#iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

So I now I am in this awkward situation where I have to edit this file to alternate between fast boots and the ability to use SSH with my Pi.

**Does anyone know how I can fix this, to satisfy both conditions?**

Comment: I didn't get; is your RPi waiting ethernet connection ?

Comment: Yes, it says something to the effect of, a start process is running for LSB: waiting for network. It will wait for 1min and then finish booting.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Create file (with subdirs)

```
/etc/systemd/system/networking.service.d/reduce-timeout.conf
```

with content:

```
[Service]
TimeoutStartSec=1
```

On my Pi model B (with Minibian) this solution resolved the problem.
Pi boot time reduced to 15 sec, and network works.

Comment: Confirmed makes huge diff on rpi3 raspbian latest Aug 2017

Answer (score 5):

Run `sudo raspi-config` and disable 4th option: **Wait for Network at Boot**.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I did that in my early troubleshooting and it does not help.

Comment: I looked in the **raspi-config** script and when you select Fast boot-no wait, it removes the file: `/etc/systemd/system/dhcpcd.service.d`/wait.conf. I checked and that file is not on my system so whatever raspi-config does for network doesn't matter because the file it uses to wait is gone.

Comment: It's now under the "Boot Options" menu in raspi-config

Answer (score 2):

I don't have the reputation to comment on the accepted answer yet. But just a quick update on the answer, for the latest Raspbian `Linux raspberrypi 4.9.59-v7+ #1047 SMP Sun Oct 29 12:19:23 GMT 2017 armv7l GNU/Linux`

The file you want to edit is:

```
/etc/systemd/system/network-online.target.wants/networking.service
```

It already exists,and you should edit the section already mentioned in the answer. In my case, from `TimeoutStartSec=5min`, to `TimeoutStartSec=1` did the trick.

Comment: It isn't necessary to use that file.   The method in the accepted answer is probably a more "best practice" solution since you are not editing a configuration which may get replaced on upgrade.

Answer (score 2):

I had no success applying the many other good solutions to my setup which involves having a macvlan interface on top of `eth0`.
Install based on `2018-06-27-raspbian-stretch-lite`.
What works well for me:

Disable `dhcpcd` service.

```
systemctl disable dhcpcd
```

Reduce timeout in `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf`.

```
# Do not hold boot for default 60 seconds, give up faster
# but not too fast, see what work with your DHCP server
timeout 10;

# Retry faster
# This is after initial give up and dhclient went to background and boot proceeded without a lease
# Default 5 minutes is too long
retry 20;

# Consider backoff-cutoff setting as well
```

So now that waits at boot for up to 10 seconds, and if there is no DHCP lease the `dhclient` goes into background and boot continues without a lease.

Without `dhcpcd` I have the added benefit of being manually stop/start/restart `wlan0` without having to hunt down `wpa_supplicant` started presumably by `dhcpcd` and which was refusing to stop with `ifdown wlan0`.
Note: this might mean you might not be able to use `rapsi-config` to configure your wifi, and need to write config into `/etc/network/interfaces`, which is preferred for me anyway.

The otherwise neat solution by Evgeniy Chukanov using `/etc/systemd/system/networking.service.d/reduce-timeout.conf` to reduce timeout causes `dhcpcd` to NOT bring up my macvlan interface IF lease timeout on `eth0` at boot gets reached.

Not that my macvlan config matters for OP, but it was the reason to come up with this solutions, so for completeness:
In `/etc/network/interfaces.d/macvlan1`

```
auto macvlan1
iface macvlan1 inet static
    address .....
    netmask .....
    pre-up ip link add macvlan1 link eth0 type macvlan
    post-down ip link del macvlan1
```

I have since swapped `eth0` and `mavclan1`, and I do static IPv4 on `eth0` and DHCP client on `macvlan1`, which gets me further even using `dhcpcd`, interface gets created, but still does not re-try to obtain lease after initial timeout.
I have not bothered to investigate further because my solution without `dhcpcd` works very well for me.

Answer (score 1):

> Does anyone know how I can fix this, to satisfy both conditions?

Perhaps, but not in a canonical way ("proper practice") way without examining the system (I've never used minibian), and learning more about how network configuration on GNU/Linux in general is *supposed* to work, because I've never used it properly.

All my debian style machines, including pis, have an `/etc/network/interfaces` that looks like your commented out version.

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Non "debian style" distros don't have this file at all -- although they'll have something roughly equivalent, which I'll also crudely disable.  I do this because the whole if-up/down autoconfig system in *my* opinion causes more problems than it solves.  However, part of *my* perspective includes the fact that I understand linux networking on a lower level well enough, and that I find scripting for this sort of thing and/or adding something to the init system myself fairly simple.  But that's a perspective that took some years to acquire.

My recommendation here would be to *leave that file as you have it* (with everything but the first two lines commented out or removed) and try adding this to `/etc/rc.local`:

```
 (
     ip link set eth0 up
     dhclient -v eth0
 ) &> /var/log/ethernet.log
```

First make sure `dhclient` is installed (`dhclient --version`), and if not install it.

Also check the system for ifplugd: `ps -C ifplugd`.  If it is in use, **disable it.**

There are some drawbacks to this:

- It assumes you are only using the pi on a wire, i.e., you don't want it to prefer or fallback on wifi.
- If you disconnect, you'll have to re-run those commands again or reboot.

If it doesn't work, have a look in `/var/log/ethernet.log`.

Comment: Thanks...but I am still curious why this would be a problem?... Rasbpian proper does not have this issue. Is there some more information I could give to help find out was is causing this?

Comment: That's getting a bit on par with trying to help someone diagnose their engine problems over the phone --  not necessarily impossible but probably not worthwhile either.   Ask the horse's mouth (i.e., the minibian creator) about it), which will probably mean email.

Comment: True.. I was hoping someone here might be using Minibian and have resolved this issue.

Comment: We don't even have a tag but I added one...

Answer (score 0):

I remove the static ip from `/boot/cmdline.txt` and that works.